# C++ returning temporary objects confusion

Tags: c++, temporary-objects

I have a rather basic C++ question: Consider a function that takes some input parameters and creates a `std::string` from those parameters like the one below:

```
std::string constructString( int some_parameter ) {
    
    std::stringstream ss;
    
    // Construct a string (arbitrarily complex)
    ss << "Some parameter is " << some_parameter << " right now";

    return ss.str();    //Am I not returning a temporary object here?
}
```

I understand that the `stringstream` object will go out of scope when the function returns, but doesn't that invalidate the constructed string as well?

What would happen if I changed the return type to `const char *` and returned `ss.str().c_str()` instead?

Code like the above seems to work, but I suspect that's just because the memory containing the 'temporary' object has not yet been overwritten with something else when I use it?

I have to admit, I'm rather confused in such situations in general; I'd appreciate it if someone could explain this whole "temporary objects" thing to me (or just point me in the right direction).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are returning a temporary object, but because you return it by value, the copy is created. If you return pointer or reference to temporary object, that would be a mistake.

If you change the return type to `const char *` and return `ss.str().c_str()` you would return pointer to some buffer of temporary `std::string` returned by `ss.str()` and that would be bad.

Answer (score 5):

As you see [Stringstream::str()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/str/) returns `std::string` object. You returns `std::string` without reference that means that without RVO(NRVO) optimization copy constructor will call and create valid `std::string` object. With optimization `std::string` will be moved without copy constructor. But if will return `std::string&` it will crash because this object will be destroyed after function return. Same effect will be with `const char *` because after destroying this pointer will point on bad memory and this is dangerous situation.

Comment: Will be destructor called after this copy will not be picked up by function calling constructString? As it is temporary object, I assume pointer to it is held on stack as a return value. What happens after it is returned? Is it destroyed if there is no new object owner? How compiler knows that object have to be destroyed or not after it is returned?

Answer (score 1):

Assume this: `T val = some_function()`, when you return a value from `some_function` C++ copy value of returned value into `val` using specified copy constructor or built-in operator. So if you return an `int` or `std::string` there is no problem at all, but if you return a pointer to a memory that will be freed at end of the function, oops!! your pointer will be pointed to an invalid memory. For example consider this:

```
const char* some_function() {
    std::string res( ... );
    //...
    return res.c_str();
}
```

You are returning pointer to data that will be freed as soon as function return(since `res` will be destroyed and it will free its internal data) so you will get the address, but that address does not point to what you possibly expect!

Comment: *"C++ copy value of returned value into val"* - Even more than that, it already copies the value returned by `ss.str()` into the function's return value, because he returns by-value. So it would even work with `const T &val = some_function()`, given `some_function` returns by-value.

Comment: `const T& val = some_function()` actually work perfectly, since C++ copy every thing by value and `const T&` is actually `const T*` with some different semantic, the problem here is `const T&` point to a location that will be invalidated after the function call complete!

Comment: No, it won't, because binding a const reference to a temporary extends the lifetime of the temporary. That's why `void foo(const std::string&); foo("test");` works perfectly fine. It won't work for a pointer (or a non-const reference), though. This is one of the small differences, that make references indeed something else than syntactic sugar for pointers.

Comment: I told you that's a pointer with different semantic, when you call `foo("test");` it will create a `std::string` and then pass its pointer as a reference to the function, but we don't have a thing such as extending life time of object in C++, this is not C# that life time is managed using references. For example if you have `const std::string& foo() {std::string tmp; return tmp;}`, reference never add life time of `tmp` and it will be destroyed at end of function! but if you have `int& foo() {int n = 5; return n;}` syntax is invalid but it work perfectly, since n is still in memory!!

Comment: Ok, the example was badly chosen, since the temporary `std::string` lifes until the end of the function call expression anyway. I also know that this is not C# and references/pointers don't usually extend any lifetime. But still this is how binding to a const reference works. I'll be right back once I have dug up the standard proof.

Comment: Got it in 12.2 [class.temporary] paragraphs 4-5 *"There are two contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the fullexpression. [...] The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. The temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference except: [list of cases not applying here]."* And it also contains an example to demonstrate it. Feel free to look it up (the current draft of the standard is free of charge).

Comment: Though, it won't work for a non-const reference, even if the standard doesn't explicitly say so. That is, because you cannot bind a mutable lvalue-reference to an rvalue in the first place. And also your comment: *"but if you have ... syntax is invalid but it work perfectly, since n is still in memory"* - is exactly opposite. The syntax is perfectly valid, but it will **not** work perfectly, it may, or it may not, since it's UB (though this might have been waht you meant with that sentence).

Comment: Also [here](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/) is a (maybe more understandable) explanation of this feature by (I'd dare to call him authority) *Herb Sutter*. In fact he uses exactly the example I used.

Comment: @ChristianRau First I should say thank you for showing this to me! But second we were talking about type of return value, not the syntax of variable that is local to a function(in your case function still return `T` not `const T&` that is certainly illegal), in my opinion(and what I believe all compilers implement for this feature is to convert you `const T&` to an actual `T` and it live until end of its scope! As far as I understand references is C++ are all syntax sugar and it is all simulated by pointer(or even ignore your reference and convert to full type)!

Comment: Yes, returning a `const T&` to a function-local variable is of course wrong, but that was never in discussion here, though. *"is to convert you const T& to an actual T and it live until end of its scope"* - No, that would be incorrect. There is no copy made or object created here, be it conceptual or real. The lifetime of the original temporary is really extended and this is how the compiler are implementing this. *"As far as I understand references is C++ are all syntax sugar"* - And this is true, except for this particular case.

Comment: *"or even ignore your reference and convert to full type"* - How this conceptual reference is mapped into actual machine code is indeed totally up to the implementation. But still language-wise, a reference is nothing else than a reference. And binding a temporary to a const-reference extends its lifetime. There is no room for interpretation here or mapping to different language constructs here. Though what the compiler does is beyond our imagination, as long as it behaves **exactly** like extending the temporary's lifetime (which a transformation into an actual `T` wouldn't by itself).

Comment: Also see the linked article by *Herb Sutter*, which in its third point describes the most amazing property of this feature, which **cannot** be emulated by merely replacing the `const T&` by a `T`.

Comment: @ChristianRau OK I give up on this, but that's not about return value of the function. Again so much thanks for showing me this, after long time of C++ coding I never thought that it can still surprise me!