# C++ string.c_str()

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

If using `g++` and `clang++`, I get `++my string==my string##my string--`. While MSVC and Intel Compiler, it is `++==my string##my string--`.

Why?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string test()
{
    string s0 = "my string";
    return s0;
}

int main()
{
    string s = test();
    const char* s1 = test().c_str();
    const char* s2 = s.c_str();
    cout << "++" << s1 << "==" << s2 << "##" << test().c_str() << "--" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is it an undefined behavior?

Comment: `s1` points to an object that no longer exists. It's definitively undefined behavior to read from it.

Comment: Don't confused undefined behavior with "undefined translation from code to assembler". Provided the observable behavior (as the term is defined by the language) remains the same, the compiler can transform the code in any way is chooses. It's known as the [as-if rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ returning temporary objects confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952295/c-returning-temporary-objects-confusion)

Comment: Why `test().c_str()` can work but `s1` not ?

Comment: Unless you put it into a variable the returned object from `test()` is destroyed immediately before the next statement begins (but after the current statement has run).

Comment: `test().c_str()` "works" but you can't use it in any meaningful way. The returned object survives until the end of the expression, which includes executing `c_str()`. However, the result of the expression is a pointer to data owned by the returned object, which is destroyed by the time you can use that address for anything.

Comment: @françois: `std::string t(test().c_str());` is silly but well-defined. Or you could pass it to a system interface which requires a `const char*`, such as `fopen`. Not that those are necessarily good style.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a comment, you asked:

> Why `test().c_str()` can work but `s1` not?

`test().c_str()` works only in some contexts, not all contexts.

```
std::cout << test().c_str() << std::endl;
```

is guaranteed to work since the temporary returned by `test()` is required to stay alive until the execution of the statement is complete.

On the other hand,

```
char const* s1 = test().c_str();
std:cout << s1 << std::endl;
```

is undefined behavior since the temporary is not required to live beyond completion of execution of the first line.